# How to represent a long composed if condition in UML

Tags: .net, uml, conditional-statements

In my code i have a long if composed condition. I need to represent it in my UML diagram and i do not have enough space to wrote the if condition into the diamond geometric figure.

Can the if condition be somehow wrote outside the diamond figure, and then set to point to the diamond figure ? Or how can i represent this nicely in UML ?

Comment: The conditions are often placed on the edges going out of the decision diamond (like in [this example](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/software-resolve-issue-uml-activity-diagram-example.html)). Can you show us the diagram you currently have that needs the better layout?

Comment: I just added something like Thomas suggested below, the condition outside the diamond, it was quite a big one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give the outgoing transition guards a simple name that reflect the choice and put the complete condition in an opaque behaviour in the guard. Then you only display the guard name for legibility on the diagram. Users who want to know more can look at the content of the opaque behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the condition in free text near the diamond. Depending on the tool you use it should be possible to even enlarge the diamond to any extend.